# Append text at the end of the line VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, text, append

I want to append some texts in a file.

I used this code to append text from a file

```
Dim Lines As List(Of String) = ReadAllLines(Script_Path_DiskPart & File_MakeVDISK).ToList()
Lines.Insert(0, Frm_Login.AmountDisk & " Type=" & ChrW(34) & "EXPANDABLE" & ChrW(34))
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Script_Path_DiskPart & File_MakeVDISK, Lines)
```

And this is what I get after `System.File.WriteAllLines(Script_Path_Diskpart & File_MakeVDISK, Lines)`

Unexpected result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Actually I want to use `System.IO.File.Append...` but I don't know how it works...

Comment: It seems that your Frm_Login.AmountDisk contains only the number 1024. If you want the other text you need to add it before that number. (And don't forget to add also an Environment.NewLine if you want to have a newline at that position)

Comment: Well if you insert into the lines array at position 0, its puts the data in position 0.  You arent appending to a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like instead of the `Lines.Insert` statement, you want to do something like this:

```
Lines(0) = Lines(0) & Frm_Login.AmountDisk & " Type=""EXPANDABLE"""
```

Note that you can escape a quote mark with another quote mark, instead of using the `ChrW`, hence the pair of doubled quotes `""` around "EXPANDABLE".

Comment: Can I use `Lines(0) &= Frm_Login.AmountDisk & " Type=""Expandable"""` instead?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.